# Block misconfigured DNS entries on BIND DNS Cache

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, bind

I'm running a web crawler with its own BIND DNS Cache. Our code resolves using our DNS cache and makes GET request with Python's requests library.

The problem is that many FQDNs are misconfigured and they point to RFC1918 IP addresses or loopback IPs like `127.0.0.1` or `10.0.0.0/8`. As a result our crawler was trying to connect these IPs and it ended with a scan report from our datacenter.

We made changes to the crawler and now it resolves ip for FQDN at first and skips it if IP is in private/loopback/reserved ranges.

After sniffing with tcpdump I found that there's still traffic going to private IP addresses. I suppose they occur because of HTTP redirects because we check the original FQDN but we don't check redirected hosts as this part occurs within Python's requests library.

Is there any option for BIND to block the resolving of private, loopback or reserved IP addresses? Can I set it to return some kind of a "not resolved" error?

**Edit:** I tried to dump BIND cache to file and checked it, now I'm sure it happens because of HTTP redirects but it's not easy to change code and I'm looking for a shortcut like configuring BIND or I will block them on firewall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With BIND you could use the [Response Policy Zone (RPZ)](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2589969) functionality to block resolution of address records (`A`/`AAAA`) referring to certain addresses.

Specifically the *RPZ-IP* type of entry is relevant:

> **RPZ-IP**
>
> IP triggers are IP addresses in an A or AAAA record in the ANSWER
>   section of a response. They are encoded like client-IP triggers except
>   as subdomains of **rpz-ip**.

As an example use-case the manual uses this:

```
; IP policy records that rewrite all responses containing A records in 127/8
;       except 127.0.0.1
8.0.0.0.127.rpz-ip      CNAME   .
32.1.0.0.127.rpz-ip     CNAME   rpz-passthru.
```

The general idea regarding what the configuration is summarized in the manual as:

> For example, you might use this option statement
>
> ```
> response-policy { zone "badlist"; };
> ```
>
> and this zone statement
>
> ```
> zone "badlist" {type master; file "master/badlist"; allow-query {none;}; };
> ```
>
> with this zone file
>
> ```
> $TTL 1H 
> @                       SOA LOCALHOST. named-mgr.example.com    (1 1h 15m 30d 2h)
>                         NS  LOCALHOST.
> ; [snip]
>
> ; IP policy records that rewrite all responses containing A records in 127/8
> ;       except 127.0.0.1
> 8.0.0.0.127.rpz-ip      CNAME   .
> 32.1.0.0.127.rpz-ip     CNAME   rpz-passthru.
>
> ; [snip]
> ```

Do read up on the details to understand the overall setup as well as the rather specific semantics inside an RPZ zone! (It has the normal zone syntax but as you can see some special names have very specific meaning.)

Comment: As a separate note, I can mention that for instance unbound has a configuration option specific to this scenario called [`private-address`](http://unbound.net/documentation/unbound.conf.html). So BIND is not the only option in terms of achieving this.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! It looks like it will solve the problem. Also I found something called "Google-DNSWall" to prevent DNS rebinding, here it is if you want to check: https://github.com/abortz/google-dnswall

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose they occur because of HTTP redirects because we check the
>   original FQDN but we don't check redirected hosts as this part occurs
>   within Python's requests library.

I hope for your sake that you flushed BIND's DNS cache after you changed your code. Moving on...

The killer is in saying "I supposed." You need to make sure. First, check to see if there are any private IP addresses in your BIND cache with `rndc dumpdb`. Look through that file for offenders.

**If there are:** Flush your cache. See if they come back. I'm not convinced that private IP addresses would be in your cache as a result of HTTP redirects. It would be very unusual for a publicly accessible website to have many instances of a HTTP redirect that brings a visitor to a hostname that resolves to a RFC 1918 IP address. Private IP addresses in public zones... *shudder*.

**If there aren't:** Then the traffic to private IP addresses is coming into the application elsewhere. Perhaps an application cache of some kind. Something in memory that you're not aware of. Perhaps a totally different process and maybe it's not your application after all.

> Is there any option for BIND to block the resolving of private,
>   loopback or reserved IP addresses? Can I set it to return some kind of
>   a "not resolved" error?

<del>No. BIND resolves, and so in your scenario you have a theoretical race condition where: You don't want the IP address, but to find out if it's an IP address you don't want, you have to get it. What you want is something of a reverse DNS RPZ, which does not exist.</del>

I am wrong. Yes, you will probably be able to use RPZ-IP as the illustrious Håkan Lindqvist points out. Check this out: http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2589969 Also [upvote his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/745901/9770).

In this case, you need to pull the logic into the application and check each and every hostname more carefully against your local cache and disallow the crawler from going to RFC 1918 addresses.

Let's break down what you say a just a bit closer:

> ...we don't check redirected hosts...

So check redirected hosts and the problem is solved without any over engineering. =)

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I'm checking the dump file now. But I need to point that they set private or loopback IP's for public zones much more than you guess (in fact lots of, if you crawl 100 millions of domains).  

What I need to do on BIND is not "not getting IP of domain" but if the resolved is in private/reserved range, returning response as "not resolved", the problem is starting after resolved IP returns to our crawler from DNS.  

And to check redirected hosts on Python's requests library, we need much more over engineering (and probably on core developers code)

Comment: @shehatesme You cannot do what you want to do with BIND. You need to do this in your application, or write a custom DNS resolver / modified BIND's own source code.

Comment: Now on named_dumb.db file, I see 10.0.5.4 resolved for a FQDN... Looks like the problem occurs because of redirections. Maybe I will block all outgoing to port 80 for whole private network on firewall.

Comment: @shehatesme That's another quick option, yes.

Comment: The RPZ feature in BIND does have this capability.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist So far I've not seen a way to blacklist IP addresses and prevent resolvers from getting responses from BIND that have those backlisted IPs. So far I've only been able to see how RPZ prevents hostnames from being resolved properly. But not already-resolved and cached records from returning IP addresses to clients. ¯\\(°_°)/¯

Comment: @Wesley See *RPZ-IP* in http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2589969 (as well as my answer covering it)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Awesome! Thanks. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @shehatesme I've updated my answer and Håkan Lindqvist has a good answer for you too.

Comment: @Wesley thank you very much for your help. After following Hakan's answer I found some other tools for this purpose. (Looks like the right term is "DNS rebinding" for this problem) Here is the one of them: https://github.com/abortz/google-dnswall